# dropdown from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, associative

Having solved the populating the dropdown from the array, the next phase of my project is pulling data from a database to allow users to put limits on the data they want to see.

Again, I'm having trouble populating the dropdown. This time however, the problem seems to be that when I put the HTML interspersed with the PHP, the whole thing stops- the form loads, but nothing goes into the drop down.

Here's the code.

```html
        //Step One: Query the DB, and get a list of monthly reports
        $sql = "SELECT Report_Text, Report_Date FROM ADM_8_Reports_List";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //print_r ($result); 
        $reports_in_db = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);



        if (sizeof($reports_in_db) > 0)
        {

                
                print_r ($reports_in_db);
                echo "\n";
        
        //Now, like the front page, create a form and populate it.
        ?>
        Choose a Monthly Report <select name = "monthly_report">

        <?php
                
                foreach($reports_in_db as $row)
                {
                        echo 'option value"' . $row ["Report_Date"] . '">'  . $$row ["Report_Date"] . " " . $row ["Report_Text"] . '</option>';
                }
        }
        else
        {
                echo "I'm sorry, there's no data here. Please start again\n";
        } ?>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="monthly report" value="Retrieve Report"">
```

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU7Cs.jpg)

what it looks like is happening is that the code is freezing where I'm interpolating the HTML and PHP, and actually creating the dropdown.

basically on the previous page, the user can choose one of 4 things to do. On this page, there's an if statement based on $_POST from the previous page. Depending on the choice, the databased will be polled to get, in this case, a list of all the monthly reports. I've copied exactly the structure of what I did on the first page (where I was going from an associative array I hard-defined). I can't figure out what's wrong with the declaration of the dropdown, but that's where the thing's .. well stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I am really annoyed by this.

I forgot '<'when declaring the option. And didn't see it until I posted the question here.

Sorry.